# how can i make one object copy form of another object?

Tags: dupli-groups

i'm new to blender so i'm hoping there's an easy solution for this)) i have these two objects with different vertex count. can i make the one with fewer vertices repeat the form of the one with more vertices without changing the vertex count of the first one? so basically i need one to mimic the other without combining anything.. thanks!
[image]

Comment: Atl+D  (will duplicate same vertex) with same effect if one is affected changes to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the *ShrinkWrap* modifier could the job you are looking for.
It allows you to *shrink* vertices of one object to the closest vertices of the other one.

[image]

---

### Steps:

1. Place the objects to the same position
2. Select the low-detail one
3. Go to modifiers tab and select *ShrinkWrap*
   [image]
4. Pick the high-detailed object as a Target

There are some useful options available in the modifier so you can look at the [ShrinkWrap Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html) overview in the Blender Manual.

Comment: thanks Jan! you've made my day)) it will have to be fine-tuned though. the target object has more verts but is smaller. so during the transformation instead of redistributing "extra" verts where they could actually be useful the algorythm bundles them up in some weird places)) my thinking is that i'll have to learn how to cut them out and increase the vertex count exactly by the amount lost in the cut.